# Subtract Dates - Jira Cloud - ScriptRunner

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

i am working on making a scripted field to obtain the age of a ticket in jira cloud using scriptrunner. For now i have been able to get the start date and end date however i am having problems while subtracting them using the {{[date1].diff([date2]).[unit]}} smartvalue.

Can you please help me out ?

```
// Fetch the issue object from the key using the Jira Software API
    def issue = get("/rest/agile/1.0/issue/${issue.key}")
        .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .asObject(Map)
        .body
        

    if (issue.fields.status.name == 'Closed') {

       
        String StartDate = issue.fields.created
        String EndDate = issue.fields.updated
        
// Format the date strings into a nicer format
    String formattedStartDate = StartDate.substring(0, 10)
    String formattedEndDate = EndDate.substring(0, 10)
    String finalTime = formattedStartDate.diff(formattedEndDate)
    
// Set the dates in the scripted field
    return " Start Date: ${formattedStartDate}  End Date: ${formattedEndDate} Age: ${finalTime) "
    
// Return a default message if the issue is not in active sprint
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the diff in days, I am using `joda.time`'s `Days` and `LocalDate`. I think ScriptRunner contains Java 8 classes, so you can use `ChronoUnit` too.

Here is a sample code:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // Set the day 00:00 to get the date only

Calendar dueDate = Calendar.getInstance();
dueDate.setTime(issue.duedate);
dueDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // Again, set the day to 00:00

LocalDate todayLD = new LocalDate(today.getTimeInMillis());
LocalDate dueLD = new LocalDate(dueDate.getTimeInMillis());

int daysBetween = Math.abs(Days.daysBetween(todayLD, dueLD).getDays());
```

By the way, you should import two libraries:

```
import org.joda.time.Days
import org.joda.time.LocalDate
```